# How do I copy the value of a large array in delphi's debugger?

Tags: delphi, debugging

I'm currently debugging some code in Delphi, and would like to see the entire contents of a large array. I've tried using "Copy Watch Value" and the regular "Copy Value", but both end up cutting off the variable when I paste into a text file.

I've looked around to see if there was any option or flag that I could set, but I didn't see anything related.

Any ideas on how to grab the complete contents of a large array when at a break point in Delphi?

[image: Picture of my watched variable]

Comment: You'd probably have to write your own debugger visualizer plugin. But it's going to be more productive for you to do this by writing some temporary debug only code that spits it to a log.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to make my own plugin. What do you think about a procedure that has a side effect of writing to the clipboard. So I can evaluate WriteArrayToClipboard(arrayValue), then paste. Or would saving it a specific log be better?

Comment: You can use CodeSite to log this value.

Comment: Whatever works and is convenient. It's debugging code so you don't need to be too squeamish

Comment: @Elric: it is pretty simple to write such a plugin, actually. See, for instance: https://github.com/rvelthuis/BigNumbers/tree/master/Visualizers

Comment: Do you need the contents of the array stored in file for evaluation or would it be enough to evaluate array contents visually? If it is the later then you can always inspect the array variable (right click on watch and chose Inspect). This will open a new window with all array items shown (each in its own line. And if not all values can fit into the window at the same time a scrollbar is added so you can scroll up and down if necessary.